# Make the windows 7 taskbar NOT always on top?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is it possible to set the windows taskbar not to appear on top of other windows? I have it set to auto-hide and it is annoying to touch it's side of the screen by accident the screen and have it popup and get in the way of the app i'm using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable 'Keep taskbar on top of other windows' in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/16961/how-do-you-disable-keep-taskbar-on-top-of-other-windows-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can handle this, some free, some not.

The best is probably this, but it does cost a little, but it also has a lot more great features, like being able to select certain programs to always be on top, or you can put programs into the systray, that normally you could not.

http://download.cnet.com/Taskbar-Hide/3000-2092_4-10302846.html

The second way is free. Auto-hide the taskbar, but move it to the right side. You can still accidentally mouse over it, and expose it, but you will probably do it a lot less. You can test with the various sides to see where you hit it the least.

Then I found this hack, originally written for XP. I have not tested it, but it removes the taskbar and gives it a hotkey. It seem like it would probably also work with Windows 7.

http://www.aeonity.com/frost/removing-windows-xp-taskbar-hack